# Getting error "Element is not currently visible so may not be interacted with for a text box which is present in window opened via ajax"

Tags: html, ajax, selenium

I am writing script in selenium using java to automate one flow in which when i am clicking on one dropdown a popup is opening which is otherwise hidden and that popup is coming via ajax call.

When I am trying to access a textbox on that popup, it is showing error, "***Element is not currently visible so may not be interacted***".

I had tried all methods mentioned in this [link](http://qeworks.com/handle-ajax-call-selenium-webdriver/), but none of them is working. Even I had tried window handle, but that also failed. I am attaching here image of that window.[image: ]]

Any help will be highly appreciated. Also the `div` in which the textbox is there, that `div's` display flag is showing false.

Comment: can you first switch to popup window  and then try locating the element.

Comment: Hey Auto, do you mean switching to popup window via window handle. If yes then I had tried it but it's not working.

Comment: do you wait for the element to become visible before attempting to interact with it?

Comment: Yes I had tried that using Webdriver wait, implicit wait, Fluent wait and Thread also.

Comment: can you add the code you tried ?

Comment: @Aditi Which options have you tried using `WebDriverWait`  with `ExpectedConditions` like `presenceOfElementLocated`or `visibilityOfElementLocated`???

Comment: here is the code that I had tried :

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried reduced to a [mcve], and what the result was... any error messages, etc. It's also very important to include any relevant HTML and properly format the HTML and code.

Answer (score 0):

**(Assuming you are using java)** You need to try using `WebDriverWait`with `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement textbox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By...));

//now you can access the textbox
textbox.sendKeys("your value");
```

If you are **still facing the same problem**, you need to implement `JavaScriptExecutor` to acess to `textbox` as below :-

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", textbox, "your value");
```

**Note** :- Because you did not mention which type accessing you want with the `textbox`, I'm giving you the **example of setting the value in the `textbox`**

Hope it will help you...:)